# Who actually last decide what is the Generic Type?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0

I have this function

```
 public static T2 MyFunc<T1, T2>( T1 a, T1 b, T2 c)
        {
            return c;
        }
```

I'm creating 2 Persons class instances:

```
 class Person
         {  }

            Person p = new Person();
            Person p2 = new Person();
```

I'm calling the function  with :

```
 MyClass.MyFunc(p, p2, 5);
```

my Question is :

Who actually decide about the T1 type  ? (p ? p2 ? )

Because if the left one is Apple so he checks that the second one is Also an apple

and if the second one is Orange - he should check that the first one is also an Orange.

[image]

It seems weird to ask it becuase at compile time they will fail if not the same.

Still - who decide about the type ?

And second  - If i change it to dynamic - on runtime- who will decide what the T1 type should be ?

Comment: There is no 'decision'. A match is found or an error occurs. Just try `MyFunc(p1, "", 5)` or `MyFunc("", p2, 5)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At a high level, method type inference works like this.

First we make a list of all the *arguments* -- the expressions you supply -- and their corresponding *formal parameter type*.

Let's look at a more interesting example than the one you give. Suppose we have

```
class Person {}
class Employee : Person {}
...
Person p = whatever;
Employee p2 = whatever;
```

and the same call. So we make the correspondences:

```
p  --> T1
p2 --> T1
5  --> T2
```

Then we make a list of what "bounds" are on each type parameter and whether they are "fixed". We have two type parameters, and we start with no upper, lower or exact bounds.

```
T1: (unfixed) upper { }  lower { }  exact { }
T2: (unfixed) upper { }  lower { }  exact { }
```

(Recall our recent discussion in another question about the relative sizes of types being based on whether or not a type was more or less restrictive; a type that is more restrictive is *smaller* than one that is less restrictive.  Giraffe is smaller than Animal because more things are Animals than are Giraffes.  The "upper" and "lower" bound sets are exactly that: the solution to the type inference problem for a given type parameter must be *larger than or identical to* every lower bound and *smaller than or identical to* every upper bound, and *identical to* every exact bound.)

Then we look at each argument and its corresponding type. (If the arguments are lambdas then we might have to figure out the *order* in which we look at arguments, but you don't have any lambdas here so let's ignore that detail.)  For each argument we make an *inference* to the formal parameter type, and add the facts that we deduce about that inference to the bound set.  So after looking at the first argument, we deduce the bounds:

```
T1: (unfixed) upper { }  lower { Person }  exact { }
T2: (unfixed) upper { }  lower { }  exact { }
```

After the second argument we deduce the bounds

```
T1: (unfixed) upper { }  lower { Person, Employee }  exact { }
T2: (unfixed) upper { }  lower { }  exact { }
```

After the third argument we deduce the bounds:

```
T1: (unfixed) upper { }  lower { Person, Employee }  exact { }
T2: (unfixed) upper { }  lower { int }  exact { }
```

After we have made as much progress as we can, we "fix" the bounds by finding the *best type in the bounds set that satisfies every bound*.

For T1, there are two types in the bounds set, `Person` and `Employee`. Is there one of them that satisfies every bound in the bounds set?  Yes. `Employee` does not satisfy the `Person` bound because `Employee` is a smaller type than `Person`; `Person` is a *lower bound* -- it means *no type smaller than `Person` is legal*. `Person` does satisfy all the bounds: `Person` is identical to `Person` and is larger than `Employee`, so it satisfies both bounds. The best type in the bounds set that satisfies every bound is for T1 is `Person` and for T2 obviously it is `int` because there is only one type in the bounds set for T2. So we then fix the type parameters:

```
T1: (fixed) Person
T2: (fixed) int
```

Then we ask "do we have a fixed bound for every type parameter?" and the answer is "yes", so type inference succeeds.

> If I change the first argument's type to `dynamic` then how is T1 inferred?

If any argument is dynamic then inference of T1 and T2 is deferred until runtime, at which point the semantic analyzer considers the *most derived accessible runtime type* of the value as the type for the lower bound supplied by the dynamic argument.

---

If this subject interest you and you want to learn more, there is a video of me explaining the C# 3 version of the algorithm here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/11/17/a-face-made-for-email-part-three.aspx

(C# 3 did not have upper bounds, only lower and exact bounds; other than that, the algorithms are pretty much the same.)

A number of articles I've written about type inference problems are here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/type+inference/

Comment: I feel like the compiler gave me an answer. thanks a lot . (again)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You're welcome. I've added some links to some helpful articles and videos if you want more information on this subject.

Comment: So C# 4 added upper bounds? Why is that? In what situations are they useful?

Comment: @svick: Upper bounds are only even *possible* when generic type inference must be made involving a *contravariant* conversion. Since C# 3 only had covariant or non-variant conversions, there was no way to ever get into a situation where there even *was* an upper bound, so we did not even bother to mention them in the algorithm. When we added covariant and contravariant conversions on generic interfaces and delegates to C# 4, we added upper bound inferences to the type inference algorithm.

Comment: Can you please tell where I can download the inference algorithm complete video of yours which you linked in your answer : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/11/17/a-face-made-for-email-part-three.aspx  and it's direct link in that blog post http://wm.microsoft.com/ms/msdn/visualcsharp/eric_lippert_2006_11/EricLippert01.wmv. I have a slow connection that's why asking :)

Comment: @M3taSpl0it: No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

The possibility to omit the types in the call

```
MyClass.MyFunc(p1, p2, 5);
```

is a syntax candy (unless you're using anonymous types), and it compiles exactly identically to

```
MyClass.MyFunc<Person, int>(p1, p2, 5);
```

The compiler deduces the values for `T1` and `T2` according to the types of the parameters `a`, `b` and `c`. If `p1` and `p2` are of incompatible types (see [svick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149708/41071), the compiler won't be able to deduce `T1` and this will result in a compilation error.

Comment: still , the compiler needs some anchor to see if he should check for apple or orange

Comment: I think the compiler does not care of what the types are, it just checks if first and second param are of the same type.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, You're talking about Persons and then you're talking about Apples and Oranges... Sorry, I'm having trouble following you :)

Comment: @IlyaKogan when the compiler see T1 he should chek if t2  ==t1 or when he sees t2 - e checks if t2==t1.

Comment: t1 == t2 is the same thing as t2 == t1, we are talking about `Type` from compiler perspective here, not any instance equals checking.

Comment: @RoyiNamir It doesn't check if `p1 == p2`. It checks if `typeof(p1) == typeof(p2)`.

Comment: It's not just syntax sugar if you're using anonymous types. And it can still compile even if `p1` and `p2` are different types.

Comment: Thanks, @svick, I edited the answer to mention anonymous types. Can you give an example where this will compile with two different types?

Comment: @IlyaKogan, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9149708/41071) for examples of that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no priority, both (a and b) should be the same, that is by design, T1 is resolved at compiling. If you change to `dynamic`, you just postpone type resolving to runtime and it will fail then instead at compiletime if the types are not the same. If you want them to be different, you need to introduce T3.

Edit:

The interesting part:

```
Orange a = new Orange();
Apple b = new Apple();
string c = "Doh.";

MyFunc<dynamic, string>(a,b,c);

public static T2 MyFunc<T1, T2>( T1 a, T1 b, T2 c) where T2 : class
{
    return (a.ToString() + b.ToString() + c.ToString()) as T2;
}
```

outputs:

```
I am an orange. I am an apple. Doh.
```

But this:

```
dynamic a = new Orange();
dynamic b = new Apple();
string c = "Doh.";

MyFunc<Apple, string>(a,b,c);
```

will throw:

```
RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'UserQuery.MyFunc<UserQuery.Apple,string>(UserQuery.Apple, UserQuery.Apple, string)' has some invalid arguments
```

However it seems I **really** need to find a good book or resource about dynamic types in C# 4.0 to understand the magic happening here.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you mean, but ... if a.GetType() is equal to b.GetType(), than that's true vice versa as well. They just both need to be T1 (as long as there is no dynamics obviously, see my edit above)

Comment: The magic in that case is extremely simple: an explicit type argument `dynamic` is treated exactly as though you'd said `object` when the expression is analyzed at runtime. If you have a specific question about something you don't understand, well, this is a question-and-answer site; consider posting a question.

Comment: It seems so obvious now, thanks for the explanation you posted.

Answer (score 1):

> Who actually decide about the T1 type ? (p ? p2 ? )

Isn't it obvious? Both of them. The types of `p` and `p2` have to be compatible. Contrary to what other answers are saying, they don't have to be the same. The actual rule is that there has to be an implicit conversion from on of the types to the other.

So, for example `MyFunc("a", new object(), 5)` is the same as `MyFunc<object, int>("a", new object(), 5)`, because `string` is implicitly convertible to `object`. As another example, `MyFunc(42L, 42, 4)` is the same as `MyFunc<long, int>(42L, 42, 4)`, because `int` is implicitly convertible to `long`.

Also, there are cases where the ability to let the compiler infer the types is not just nice, it's necessary. Specifically, that happens when using anonymous types. For example `MyFunc(new { p = "p" }, new { p = "p2" }, 5)` can't be rewritten to specify the types explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

"Who actually decide about the T1 type ? (p ? p2 ? )"

Normally, the C# compiler decides this. If one of the method arguments is dynamic, then the decision is done at runtime (by the Microsoft.CSharp library).
In both cases, the type inference algorithm described in the C# specification is applied:
 Both the types of `p` and `p2` are added to `T1`'s *set of lower bounds* (*upper bounds* are also possible, but only when contravariant generics are involved).

Then, the compiler picks one of the types in the set of bounds that also satisfies all other bounds.
When there is only one bound because `p` and `p2` have the same type, this choice is trivial.
Otherwise (assuming only lower bounds are involved), that means the compiler picks a type so that all other candidate types are implicitly convertible to that type (what svick's answer describes).

If there is no unique such choice, type inference fails - another overload gets chosen if possible, otherwise a compiler error occurs (when the decision is done at runtime (dynamic), an exception is thrown instead).

Comment: You meant to say *contravariant* generics.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Oops, I always mix the terms covariance/contravariance up. I actually looked them up when writing this question, and somehow still managed to write down the wrong one.
Thanks for using in/out in C#, that's much easier to remember.

Answer (score 0):

At compile time if the types are explicit then the compiler will check the types of parameters passed, and see if they correspond and can be matched to types in the generics (no conflicts).

Anyway, the real check is done at "runtime" the generic code will compile as generic anyway (unlike c++ templates). And then when the JIT compiler compiles the line it will check and see if it can create the method according to the templates you gave it, and the parameters sent.