# What is bounds pertaining to type inference?

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who actually last decide what is the Generic Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149389/who-actually-last-decide-what-is-the-generic-type)

As my question title says can anyone please explain me **what is bounds (upper bound, lower bound, exact bound) and how do they play role in type inference with examples?**

Consider simple code :

```
void func<T> ( T firstparam , T secondparam) { }
```

and caller call it

```
func( 23 , 23.23 );
```

What are the bounds while type inference process happens and how they are used by inference process?. Should my presented example is way trivial and will not have any upper bounds etc, please include your own example which will represent the idea.

Comment: Eric Lippert makes a good explanation of **bounds** in type inference in C# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/10/02/how-do-we-ensure-that-method-type-inference-terminates.aspx

Comment: @NasmiSabeer They maybe called just bounds?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Thanks for articles , it seems explaining everything )

Comment: This question is answered by my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149389/who-actually-last-decide-what-is-the-generic-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your examples there are no bounds in type inference. If you call it like

```
 func( 23 , 23.23 );
```

Then candidates for types would be `int` and `double`. `Int` can be casted implicitly to `double` but not vise-versa, so the fixed type for `T` is `double`. This has nothing to do with bounds, but type compatibility.

But however, if you call it like

```
func( new object() , 23.23 );
```

Then the upper bound for `T` will be `object`, the lower bound will be `double`. In such case fixed type for `T` will be `object`.

Eric Lippert describe what **bounds** are and why they separate lower, upper and exact bounds at blogpost on [How do we ensure that method type inference terminates?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/10/02/how-do-we-ensure-that-method-type-inference-terminates.aspx)

Jon Skeet describe in detail the process of type inference at **9.4.3 Two-phase type inference** in his wonderful book C# in Depth. Please read carefully his description for type inference for listing **9.11**

Comment: The question makes sense now!  It was just a bad example that confused it.

Comment: @Ilya +1 for shading more lights onto the question

Comment: thanks for answer , can you explain how it's determined which type should go in upper bound section and which should go in lower etc ? . Also how inference consider these bounds?

Comment: Well author indeed explained very good but bounds were never touched I guess?

Comment: I will update my answer a bit, but I don't want to retell Eric's blogpost - topic is non-trivial and I might make mistakes in terminology. Moreover, it is basically used by the compiler team, not by regular developers, as I might guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you mean by *type bounds*, but in your example, `23` is an `int`, `23.23` is a double, and an `int` is automatically convertible to a `double`.  Thus, since the compiler can treat both parameters as the same type (`double`), it infers that `T` is `double`.

Comment: Well It's given in C# in depth (section 9.4), page -249

Comment: +1, @HolyKiller, please provide the definition inline in the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I had initially thought most of C# peoples are already aware of these terminology:)